# ORA-00936: missing expression. why I get this message?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case-when

I mean I try everything using `begin` and `end` but it doesnt work.
How can I fix this?

```
select
     case 
    when exists
    (select ORG_UNIT_NAME from aaa.bbb 

    where ORG_UNIT_NAME ='ccc' and created_Date=to_date('01/11/2012','dd/mm/yyyy') )

    then

    update  aaa.bbb 
    set PROJECT_QUOTA=555 where ORG_UNIT_NAME  ='ccc' and created_Date=to_date('01/11/2012','dd/mm/yyyy')


    else
    'asd'


    end as exist_
    from dual
```

If I use 'ddd'  after then instead of update it  s work but why update isnt working.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, the `CASE` construct is not a flow control structure. Think of it of a generalised version of `COALESCE()`. You can't fit a full `UPDATE` query inside!

You probably want your main query to be of `UPDATE` type rather than `SELECT`. You can find some complex examples at http://psoug.org/reference/update.html

Comment: I know you really want it but Oracle won't make an exception for you. You need to use the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To only update based on a condition, just add it to the WHERE clause. But guess what - you already had it in there. This query should do what you want - does it?

```
update  aaa.bbb 
set PROJECT_QUOTA=555 
where ORG_UNIT_NAME  ='ccc' and created_Date=to_date('01/11/2012','dd/mm/yyyy')
```